# Как реализовать многопоточное выполнение множества мелких задач?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я отправляю письмо пользователю (пользователям). Но участок кода, где отправляется письмо, выполняется долго, из-за этого я создал  внутри основного потока второй поток и в нем осуществляю отправку. Все работает  хорошо.

Вопрос вот в чем: Второй поток после окончания выполнении  функции `run()` уничтожается автоматически или я должен что-то делать?

Просто думаю, если будет много пользователей, для каждого создавать поток, это съест ресурсы?

Comment: Если в нем не будет ссылок на внешние объекты, то удалится. И да, ресурсы съест. Используй ExecutorService http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 3):

> Второй поток, после окончания выполнении функции run() уничтожается автоматически

В общем-то да. Но работать с потоками на уровне класса Thread или Runnable неэффективно. Гораздо лучше использовать пул рабочих потоков, которому вы будете отдавать задачи на обработку (на каждого пользователя может быть 1 или несколько задач, в зависимости от реализации).

Рекомендую посмотреть на возможности класса [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Экземпляру ThreadPoolExecutor вы можете отдавать задачи с помощью метода [`public void execute(Runnable command)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-). Он создает один или несколько рабочих потоков, отдавая им задачи. Пока есть свободный поток, новый создан не будет, что экономит ресурсы. Есть возможность задать максимально допустимое число потоков.

Преимущества перед очередью из соседнего ответа:

- Не один поток, а несколько, между которыми Executor будет сам выполнять задачи.
- Количество рабочих потоков можно конфигурировать в рантайме, подстраивая его под возможности железа.
- Когда задачи кончаются, не останавливается, а ждет.

Кстати, а почему письмо отправляется долго? Вы же не прикрепляете к каждому по свежеиспеченному биткойну? Подозреваю, что код отправки письма — асинхронный, он ждет какой-нибудь реакции сервера. В таком случае, может быть рациональнее модифицировать именно этот код, выделить асинхронные задачи и отдавать их пулу в виде [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Тогда используется метод [`public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29), он возвращает экземпляр [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать так.

1. Открываете один поток для отправки.
2. Создаете в нем `Queue` который собирает очередь
3. Запускаете этот класс в отдельном (одним) потоком
4. Создаете безконечный цикл `canWork = true; while(canWork){...}`
5. В цикле отправляете письма.
6. Из любого другого класса вызываете метод этого класса для получения объекта и сохранения в поток.

У вас будет один поток для всех.